# Trigger to Process ORDImage Before Insert

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle-apex

I would like to shrink uploaded pictures to the right size before they are inserted into the database.

In Apex I have created a simple form that allows the user to upload a file and I have set up the following trigger.

```
create or replace TRIGGER new_post
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON posts

FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
  --l_image := ORDSYS.ORDImage.Init();
  --SELECT image INTO l_image FROM posts WHERE posts.post_id = :old.post_id FOR UPDATE;
   ORDSYS.ORDImage.process(:new.image, 'maxscale=200 200');

  :new.user_id := v(':APP_USER');
END;
```

This compile fine but when I try and upload an image the following error is produced:

```
1 error has occurred

ORA-29400: data cartridge error
IMG-00730: unable to process empty image
ORA-06512: at "ORDSYS.ORDIMERRORCODES", line 75
ORA-06512: at "ORDSYS.ORDIMERRORCODES", line 65
ORA-06512: at "ORDSYS.ORDIMERRORCODES", line 29
ORA-06512: at "ORDSYS.ORDIMG_PKG", line 121
ORA-06512: at "ORDSYS.ORDIMAGE", line 1366
ORA-06512: at "MATTHEWLAWS.NEW_POST", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'MATTHEWLAWS.NEW_POST'
```

Where am I going wrong?

I would also like to create another thumbnail to be placed in the same table.

Answer (score 0):

See the below link for more details, but basically blobs are not supported in triggers. So you are attempting to process what the database sees as an empty field.

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:487421613802